# First promise inside Promise.all() doesn't execute properly

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

the `wait` function is used as a sleep function, `fn` function takes an array (items), it logs each item and sleeps for a second before logging the next item.

```js
const wait = async(time) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}

const fn = async(items) => {
  for (item of items) {
    await wait(1000)
    console.log(item)
  }
}

const exeAll = async() => {
  Promise.all([
    fn(['A1', 'A2']),
    fn(['B1', 'B2']),
  ])
}

exeAll()
```

The problem is the result provided by `exeAll` function which prints:

```
B1
A2
B2
B2
```

But I think it should print something like:

```
A1
B1
A2
B2
```

A1 doesn't show at all when the above code is executed. Can anybody explain why ?

Comment: If you `await` the calls to `fn()` in the `Promise.all()` call, it works exactly as you expect.

Comment: and B2 is always logged twice at the end.

Comment: There's no need for `exeAll` to be async.

Comment: I don't want to `await` them, awaiting them makes them execute in order. which would print:
A1 A2 B1 B2

Comment: I have removed the `async` keyword from exeAll function and nothing changed, the problem is always there. `A1` is not printed and `B2` is printed twice.

Comment: @Pointy using `await` inside promise.all kinda kills the point of using it, makes your code sequential

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`for (item of items) {` will create an implicit global variable `item`, i.e. multiple calls to `fn` will interfere with each other, overwriting `item`. Properly declare the variable and it works as expected:

```js
const wait = async(time) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}

const fn = async(items) => {
  for (let item of items) {
  //   ^^^^
    await wait(1000)
    console.log(item)
  }
}

const exeAll = async() => {
  Promise.all([
    fn(['A1', 'A2']),
    fn(['B1', 'B2']),
  ])
}

exeAll()
```

---

We can add more logging to `fn` to see what happens when in your case:

```js
const wait = async(time) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}

let counter = 0;
const fn = async(items) => {
  const c = counter++;
  console.log(`enter fn call #${c}`);
  for (item of items) {
    console.log(`fn call #${c} sets item <-`, item);
    await wait(1000)
     console.log(`fn call #${c} reads item ->`, item);
    console.log(item)
  }
}

const exeAll = async() => {
  Promise.all([
    fn(['A1', 'A2']),
    fn(['B1', 'B2']),
  ])
}

exeAll()
```

---

Strict mode (`"use strict";`) would have caught that mistake because assigning to an undeclared variable throws an error.

Comment: Strict mode (`"use strict";`) would have caught that because assigning to undeclared variables throws an error ;)

Comment: Exactly. "strict mode" is the first thing that came to my mind when I first saw your answer.